# How to rewrite typewriter effect function in order for it to work on any text the program outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey I already have this code for the typewriter effect.

```
import time,os,sys

message = "example"

def typewriter(message):
        for char in message:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()

            if char!="\n":
                time.sleep(0.05)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.025)

os.system("cls") #clear
typewriter(message)
```

Now I only want to paste in into my code once and print any text that's outputted by the program with the typewriter effect and not only message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by patching [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?#sys.stdout) with [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

```
import sys
import time
from unittest import mock

class Typewriter:
    def write(self, message: str):
        for char in message:
            sys.__stdout__.write(char)
            sys.__stdout__.flush()

            if char != "\n":
                time.sleep(0.05)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.025)

@mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=Typewriter)
def main(typewriter):
    print("Hello!")

main()
```

Now all calls to `print` that originate from `main` or functions that have been called from `main` will use `Typewriter.write` instead of the regular `sys.stdout.write`.

Note that it's a very naïve implementation that only allows writing in the typewriter style, but you won't be able to call `sys.stdout.flush` from `main`, for example, because the `Typewriter` class doesn't implement this method. You can inherit from [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) and implement the missing methods if you need them.

---

Or, if you want to just copy & paste code, you can patch the `print` function itself:

```
def print(*args, file=Typewriter(), **kwargs):
    __builtins__.print(*args, file=file, **kwargs)
```

All of that are pretty horrible hacks, though. You should be calling your `typewriter` function instead.

### What you should paste for everything to "just work"

```
# Paste this at the very beginning of your file
import sys, time

class Typewriter:
    def write(self, message: str):
        for char in message:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()

            if char != "\n":
                time.sleep(0.05)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.025)

def print(*args, file=Typewriter(), **kwargs):
    __builtins__.print(*args, file=file, **kwargs)
```

Note that this will make *all* calls to `print` output stuff with the typewriter effect.

Comment: I pasted into my code, but it doesn't work. Do I need to change something about my already existing code? It just prints "Hello!" in the typewriter effect.

Comment: Yes, you need to make `main` the entry point of your program. Or just do `sys.stdout = Typewriter()` at the beginning of your code (but after `import sys`, of course).

Comment: @TheDeterminer, I've added a version that you can just paste into your code

Comment: So what do I do if I only want it to typewrite certain functions or even just a few print commands within an function?

Comment: @TheDeterminer, decorate these functions with `mock.patch` as I did with `main`. You can also create a global file object like `FO = Typewriter()` and then `print` to it every time you want to invoke the typewriter effect: `print("Hello,", "world!", file=FO)`.